# Linked Movie Clips Remove Completely and Replace, How to Set it up

Tags: flash, replace, linked-list

I made a little flash game and now I am switching things around.

First frame I have a default movieclip placed in it, and a button. Clicking the button adds a linked movieclip that contains all parts of the functioning game, and removes itself. So now start screen gone.

That part works, and the game is still just as functional as before.

Now, tried literally at least 50 different things, and I can't get it to do what I want.

When you lose the game, I am wanting to remove the movieclip containing the functional game, and add a new child, the win or lose movieclip.

[most of it I use a containAll "root" movieclip to have that prefix.]

It, at least, appears to remove the game movieclip, the win/ lose displays on the front, but the game movieclip is still "active" the listeners are still running the gameLoop.

Anyone know what I can do? or, really, a better design than this. If code needed I can paste, right now it is messy trying absolutely everything.

Thanks.

Comment: It is really difficult to tell what are you trying to ask. Could you write your question more clearly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It, at least, appears to remove the game movieclip, the win/ lose
>   displays on the front, but the game movieclip is still "active" the
>   listeners are still running the gameLoop.

Removing a `MovieClip` or any object from the stage (or, for that matter, setting the object to `null`) won't clean up its events listeners, which will continue running and will prevent the object from being **Garbage Collected** and your game might end up having **memory leaks**.

What you should do is, when you remove the object (the game `MovieClip`) from the stage, invoke a 'cleanUp' function where you should:

- remove **all** Event Listeners

  ```
  //for example, let's say that earilier in your code 
  //you add an enter frame listener:
  this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame);

  //on your clean up function you should do:
  this.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame);
  ```

Make sure to remove all of its children's event listeners as well!

- Stop all timers (and remove their listeners)

This is a great question/answer for further reference on AS3 clean up: [Am I doing AS3 reference cleanup correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2869351/am-i-doing-as3-reference-cleanup-correctly)

Comment: Thanks, danii, that was exactly the problem, and now fixed, all the errors are gone. One thing I am wondering about, is I have animated "damage" numbers. I don't keep track of them, they have an event listener and when finished remove the listener and itself. I don't keep track of them, so when the game ends and they are still on the screen, is there anyway to get rid of them at the same time?

Comment: I guess you have two options, either "keep track of them" by storing a reference to the objects in global vars and when finished remove them from stage (by doing objToRemove.parent.removeChild(objToRemove) OR (and I would prefer this method) put them "inside" another MovieClip of which you do have reference and are already removing when finished, for example set them as childs of the actual game screen.